# Apply Erlang configuration file (for multiple applications) to Common Test with rebar

Tags: configuration, erlang, rebar, common-test

I have created a configuration file as described in [Erlang -- config](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html) for my application that consists of multiple sub-apps of which each has its own Common Test suites directory. For building and testing I use rebar, my directory structure looks like this

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── ebin
│   │   └── src
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── ebin
│   │   ├── logs
│   │   ├── rebar.config
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── test
│   ├── ...
├── deps
├── rebar.config
├── apps.config
```

where `apps.config` contains the configuration for all apps. When I start my VM with `erl -pa deps/*/ebin -pa apps/*/ebin -config apps` everything works fine. I've added `{ct_extra_params, "-erl_args -config rpm"}.` to my `rebar.config` but when I run `rebar ct` an error occurs when `application:get_env/1,2` is called.

If it is not possible to do this with rebar, it would also be possible to use make instead if someone could tell me how I can accomplish it there. I know that I can somehow load configs into Common Test as described in [Erlang -- External Configuration Date](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/config_file_chapter.html) but I thought there would be an easier way if I already have `apps.config`.

**Update:** `ct_run -dir apps/app1/test -pa deps/*/ebin -pa apps/*/ebin -erl_args -config rpm` also works as expected. I guess the problem is that rebar changes the cwd when running the tests for each application and therefore the `-config rpm` option does not point to a existing file. I was anyway not able to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I now created a `Makefile` that solves the problem for me:

```
SUBDIRS = ./apps/app1 \
    ./apps/app2 \
    ./apps/app3

all: compile

compile:
    rebar compile

test:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        mkdir -p $$dir/logs; \
        ct_run -dir $$dir -logdir $$dir/logs -pa deps/*/ebin -pa apps/*/ebin -erl_args -config rpm; \
    done

.PHONY: all compile test
```

Now I can run the tests with `make test`. Anyway, if anyone knows how I can do this with rebar, please answer!

Comment: We gave up on using rebar to run CT tests, fwiw.